# Cant get the input to have a response (Chatbot)

Tags: c++, chatbot

**I want the code to answer the question or the input but i cant figure out how. i fixed this once before but i lost the file and EXE, how would i get the question have a response?**

I want the user to enter a question or a conversation and the chatbot responds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <locale>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main

(int argc, char **argv)
{

string input;

cout << "Hello there" << endl;
{

for(;;)
{

std::cin.
ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

here is the input and i cant get it to respond.

```
if (input == "hi")
cout << "hey what's up?" << endl;
else;
if (input == "hey")
cout << "hey, what's up?" << endl;
else;
if (input == "hello")
cout << "Hey, what's up?" << endl;
if (input == "how are you?")
cout << "I am good, how are you?" << endl;
if (input == "fine")
cout << "that's good" << endl;
if (input == "hru")
cout << "i am good, how are you?" << endl;
if (input == "good")
cout << "thats good" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <locale>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main

(int argc, char **argv)
{

string input;

cout << "Hello there" << endl;
{

for(;;)
{

std::cin.
ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

if (input == "hi")
cout << "hey what's up?" << endl;
else;
if (input == "hey")
cout << "hey, what's up?" << endl;
else;
if (input == "hello")
cout << "Hey, what's up?" << endl;
if (input == "how are you?")
cout << "I am good, how are you?" << endl;
if (input == "fine")
cout << "that's good" << endl;
if (input == "hru")
cout << "i am good, how are you?" << endl;
if (input == "good")
cout << "thats good" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
if (input == "")
cout << "" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the input? std::cin >> input;

Comment: Where are you getting input? I don't see anything like `cin >> input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you've decided to use `ignore`? If you replace that entire line with

```
std::cin >> input;
```

It should work fine.

Just a note. You have a few empty else statements because of the `;` and not all if statements have an else, so the program goes through multiple of them.